# Trying to get table row hovering background color to work with zebra striping rows

Tags: jquery, css, hover, alternating

I'm willing to do the best method for IE8+

I'm wanting alternating row colors (`#fff`, `#efefef`) for my table and also have a hovering effect so the background changes to `#D2DEE8`.  I would love to just use `:hover` and `:nth-child(odd)` in CSS but I've found these methods dont work with IE8.

I was using jQuery for the hovering but it eliminates the alternating colors (which at the moment I'm using nth-child(odd) to create) whenever I hover and then leave that row.

```
    $(".DefaultTable tr").not(".DefaultTable .nohover").hover(
        function () {
            var color = $(this).css('background')
            $(this).css('background', '#D2DEE8');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css('background', color);
        }
    );
```

If anyone can help me figure this out OR provide a easier/better way of doing either, the hovering or alternating rows for IE8, I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: There's code in twitter bootstrap for doing this http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) and [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) for different row colors. Use [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3ahover) for the hover effect. Testet with IE8.

javascript:

```
$(".DefaultTable tr:odd").css('background-color', '#EFEFEF');
$(".DefaultTable tr:even").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
```

css:

```
.DefaultTable tr:hover {
    background-color: #D2DEE8 !important;
}
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/H8ukq/1/).

Comment: You'll want to use .addClass because I know in IE8 `!important` does not overrides element styles. Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/H8ukq/2/

Comment: I've tested my example with IE8 and had no problems.

Comment: No problems with `!important` (also see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#attributes)) and `:hover` (see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#pseudoclasses)) with IE8.

Comment: This works great. I just have to figure out why the hover is not working on my page but is on jsfiddle. Thanks! :)

Comment: I know what it is, but it does not override element styles.

Comment: @user1090389, what do you mean?

Comment: Apparently I was mistaken from one of my past experiences, either code should work...

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the `color` declaration to the common scope:

```
var color; //At this point, the `color` variable can be read by both functions
$(".DefaultTable tr").not(".DefaultTable .nohover").hover(
    function () {
        color = $(this).css('background')
        $(this).css('background', '#D2DEE8');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css('background', color);
    }
);
```

A **better** approach would be using classnames:

CSS:

```
.special-color {
    background: #D2DEE8;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".DefaultTable tr").not(".DefaultTable .nohover").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('special-color');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('special-color');
    }
);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working in IE for me... although it works fine in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I use following codes for zebra color and mouseover as well row selection even this code will work on Ajax calling also...try it

```
function rowHighlight(){        
    $(function(){
    $("#facCodes tr:odd").addClass('oddRow');
    $("#facCodes tr:even").addClass('evenEven');
    $('#facCodes tr').hover(function() {
          $(this).addClass('hover');
       },
       function() {
          $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

});
 $('#facCodes tr').click(function(event){
    $(this).addClass("click").siblings().removeClass("click");
 });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try to do similar thing, I found out that `td` has no transparent background in IE.

`.DefaultTable tr td {background-color:transparent}`

and do it like scessor's example